# How to get different extra from different Notification

Tags: android, notifications

I sent some notification:

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, AutoEdviserActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("id",i);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            this,
                            0,
                            resultIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
int mNotificationId = i+900;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

With flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, when I see more one notification and push those which I get early, in AutoEdviserActivity I getExtra from last notification.

Another flags as I understand, unsuitable to:  FLAG_ONE_SHOT, FLAG_NO_CREATE, FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

How can I get different Extra from different Notifications?

Comment: use unique `requestCode` ?

Comment: @pskink yes, every notification has different i (id)

Comment: i did not say about notification id, i meant `requestCode`

Comment: @pskink I do not use requestCode in my example, where should I use it?

Comment: you are using three methods (`PendingIntent#getActivity` / `NotificationCompat.Builder#setContentIntent` / `NotificationManager#notify`) check their javadocs